# I cannot link my JS file in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html and JS file are located in the same folder:

```
templates/index.html
templates/my_jQuery.js
```

Here is my path code in html:

```
<script src="my_jQuery.js"></script>
```

Edit:

It works fine on JSfiddle.com, bot not on my localhost :/

http://jsfiddle.net/52jj18t8/

Comment: why don't you just name it jQuery.js or jQuery.min.js

Comment: what if you give full path? also, what errors do you get?

Comment: @steveniseki: Because it will collide with another js file.?

Comment: @fedorqui I don't have any errors. Just my jquery function doesn't work. When I write it in html file it works fine.

Comment: If you are in Chrome or Firefox you can open the console and see the errors. This way you can see if it is imported properly, etc. You can try and add a dummy function and see if it works, for example.

Comment: @fedorqui: I got GET 404 :<

Comment: Strange. I would try and add the full path. Also, related: http://superuser.com/questions/690136/404-not-found-error-for-javascript-files-when-accessing-web-page-on-localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my web framework - Flask by default set path for external files to 'static' folder

Answer (score 1):

I think you put an excessive underscore ^^

Comment: Edited. Nah, it wasn't it. I just typed it wrong when writing that post.

Comment: Have you tried to add type="text/javascript" in your script tag ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need the tilde to show how to route all the way to your folder.

```
<script src="~/my_jQuery.js"></script>
```